# \eqref for systems

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

Is there anyway to create a single label for a system of equations instead of just one, such that I can recall it?
I've done this but the result doesn't totally make sense.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}
{\end{array}\right.}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
\label{eq:conditions}
\sum_{\substack{i}}
n_{i}=N\\
\sum_{\substack{i}}
n_{i}\epsilon_{j}=E
\end{cases}
\]

blahblahblahblah \eqref{eq:conditions}
\end{document}
```

This is what the system looks like. All fine but the equation number is missng.

[image: This is what the system looks like. All fine but the equation number is missng]

[image: And this is what \eqref gives back. I cannot get where that 2 is coming from.]

And this is what `\eqref` gives back. I cannot really understand where that `2` is coming from since there is no number for the system.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the (numbered) `equation` environment and move the `label`

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:conditions}
```

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:conditions}
    \begin{cases}
        \sum_{\substack{i}} 
        n_{i}=N             \\
        \sum_{\substack{i}} 
        n_{i}\epsilon_{j}=E 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

blahblahblahblah \eqref{eq:conditions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP's use of `\substack` makes me think he/she actually wants both lines to be in displaymath style, even though the screenshot suggests otherwise. To achieve the displaymath-style look automatically, he/she could load the `mathtools` package and uses `dcases` instead of `cases`.

Comment: @Mico indeed, it is hard to tell :) Perhaps it is a remnant of the OP's actual code, and we're just seeing a MWE? Either way, your comment will be helpful for him/her :)

Comment: Congrats, by the way, on passing the 50K reputation mark!!

Comment: @Mico thank you, you're very kind :) Technically I need 20 more points, but it feels good to be so close! Thanks :)

Comment: Oops, I was jumping the gun a bit there... Hopefully two kind souls will very soon upvote your answer. :-)